# Wrong gravity applied to LinearLayout items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gravity

After applying Gravity properties to my XML items, they don't seem to be positioned in the right place. How can these issues be fixed so that the following conditions are met?:

1. The 'move up' button needs to be at the top of the screen
2. The 'move down' button needs to be at the bottom of the screen
3. The `GridView` needs to be in the vertical centre of the screen

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
        android:text="move up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
        android:text="move down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE (akshay_shahane's suggestion)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
        android:text="move up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:onClick="moveup_click"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
        android:text="move down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:onClick="movedown_click"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: why you are not using weights? for move up 0.1, grid 0.8 and move down 0.1

Comment: @akshay_shahane I did but the gravity of the GridView keeps playing up! It doesn't go to the vertical centre!

Comment: tried setting root layout gravity to centerVertical?

Answer (score 0):

Either set the weight of the `GridLayout` to 1 and `layout_height` to 0dp like this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
        android:text="move up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
        android:text="move down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or wrap the grid layout in another container like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
        android:text="move up"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
        android:text="move down"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The second option would be better because it allows the `GridLayout` to be centered by using `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
        android:text="move up"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
        android:text="move down"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set gridview weight to 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_moveup"
    android:text="move up"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/abslistview_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_movedown"
    android:text="move down"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```